# Create and format volume dynamically in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-ec2, storage, user-data

I got an EC2, create with Terraform, with 7 disks (1 root and 6 EBS).
As Terraform create and attach my disk on my EC2 randomly I can't base my user data on the partition number for the disk initialisation/volume creation and format.

So I wanted to create a powershell what will be capable get my disk number and process all actions dynamically.
The details of my disk are as followed :

| Disk_Name | Disk_letter | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MSSQL_System | D | 50 GB |
| MSSQL_Data | E | 500 GB |
| MSSQL_Log | F | 500 GB |
| MSSQL_TempDB | G | 500 GB |
| MSSQL_Backup | H | 500 GB |

As all disk have the same config (type=gp3/iops/etc) I don't care if the D is the 1st or the 2sd 50GB disk.

I tried
`Get-Disk | Where-Object{$_.PartitionStyle -eq 'RAW' -and $_.TotalSize -eq '50 GB'}` to filter the 50GB disks and create a partition, but I wasn't able to filter them

Comment: Try -gt instead of -eq.  The sizes are not exactly the size displayed.